# How to store large datasets in python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, bigdata

I have a few terabytes of data that I want to store and be able to lookup at a fast speed. Of course I cannot simply use a python dictionary as the size of that is limited by the size of my RAM.

I tried using dbm python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html, but it's too slow for my application.

Comment: What kind of operations do you need to do on your data?

Comment: I don't imagine a dictionary would work well for storing terabytes of data since it's all in memory. There are many file formats for big data, one example is HDF5 which is supported by the [Pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: Sure, but you'd need terabytes of RAM, then probably something like Redis. Honestly, this would be a lot of fun to play around with.

Comment: @EricWang Storage, retrieval, mutation. Atomic operations would be nice also. Also, getting all the keys of the dictionary, so I can iterate over it. These would be the big ones.

Comment: @PyNoob Yes. That's true. However, those are too slow for my application.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'll look into that. How is its performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at work done by Neueda at https://github.com/blu-corner/heliumdb
There a few important features that this interface provides:
1. It uses the native dictionary interface, so you really don't need to use a new API and your code doesn't have to change
2. It is fast. Much faster than using a database underneath
3. You can have your dictionary in a separate server and have multiple Python programs share the same dictionary. Of course you still need to take care of concurrency control at the application level but the dictionary is always consistent across all the programs. For string types the performance comes close to native in memory dictionary. Hope that helps. If you want I can send you some sample code

Comment: Awesome. That sounds interesting. I'll look into that. Since the performance is close to that of the in-memory, native python dictionaries, would the bottleneck on its speed be network bandwith?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a disk-based key-value store. Something like [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb) might work with [Python wrapper library](https://plyvel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user.html#getting-started) whilst maintaining performance

Comment: Since it's disk based, wouldn't that be very slow?